# Re-publishing existing package results in Invalid semver

Tags: npm

I am trying to re-publish [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mssql) 10.0.0 as `mssql-10` so as to allow side-by-side use with the `mssql` v3 I have in an existing app. (I want to do incremental migration to v10, function by function over an extended duration.)

The only changes I made on a clone of the existing v10 package, in the current folder, are the `name` and `description` attributes in package.json. Then when I ran `npm publish`, I got:

```
Error: invalid semver: 
    at patchManifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmpublish\lib\publish.js:87:7)
    at publish (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmpublish\lib\publish.js:31:23)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\publish.js:128:43
    at otplease (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\otplease.js:4:18)
    at Publish.exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\publish.js:128:13)
    at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:134:5)
```

Of which object's version number is it referring to? The `version` in package.json is still the original 10.0.0, which looks like a valid semver. Even if I changed it to 1.0.0 the same error is still there.

Is the way I am re-publishing an existing package with a new name correct? I merely clone the original package to the current folder, modify the `name` attribute, and `npm publish` from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it out and it seems to be working

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql-10

These are the steps I've followed.

- `git clone https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql`
- checkout the tag v10.0.0

  - `git checkout tags/v10.0.0 -b myBranch`

[image: Github screenshot]

- open `package.json` and change the package `name`, `description` and `version` to 10.0.0
- `npm publish` (assuming you've run  `npm adduser` before)

Note:
you can also look into npm alias where you need not republish.
https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0001-package-aliases.md

```json
{
...,

   "dependencies": {
      "mssql": "npm:msssql@^3.0.0",
      "mssql-10": "npm:mssql@^10.0.0"
   }
}
```

Also please check the npm version, it looks like you might be using an older version of NPM, as the stacktrace you've shared belongs to an older version of npm publish.

Comment: Thanks. I am curious why `version` in package shows 9.1.1, even for the one tagged v10?

Comment: the package json isn't used for release, if you see the gihub actions for the release, you'd see that it calls npx semantic-release.  https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/blob/3d2025729e21c7f4a9ef43289fa0e819e6336037/.github/workflows/nodejs.yml#L193C4-L193C34

and the logs shows that semantic-release updates the package json in ci box
https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/actions/runs/6091884705/job/16529543373#step:6:54

Comment: Gibberish to me. But npm aliasing is what I actually need. Was Googling for this and the answers I saw were all pre-availability of this feature.